# wxlistctrl align column image on center

Tags: c++, bitmap, alignment, wxwidgets, listctrl

As the title, I can't align an image to the center of a cell in a wxwidget listctrl. As in the attached image you can see the image is everytime aligned to the left. How can I put in the center?
Thanks a lot in advance.

[image: wxlistctrl cell alignment]

```
    wxBitmap imgCheck(wxT("./immagini/checked.png"), wxBITMAP_TYPE_PNG);
    wxBitmap imgUnCheck(wxT("./immagini/unchecked.png"), wxBITMAP_TYPE_PNG);
    ...
    
    lstUtenti = new wxListCtrl(this,wxID_ANY, wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(780, -1), wxLC_REPORT|wxLC_SINGLE_SEL);
    ...

    wxImageList* imgCheckUncheck = new wxImageList(32,32);
    lstUtenti->AssignImageList(imgCheckUncheck, wxIMAGE_LIST_SMALL);
    int check = imgCheckUncheck->Add(imgCheck);
    int unCheck = imgCheckUncheck->Add(imgUnCheck);
    ...
    
    lstUtenti->AppendColumn("Notifiche", wxLIST_FORMAT_CENTRE);
    lstUtenti->AppendColumn("Eventi", wxLIST_FORMAT_CENTRE);
    ....

    lstUtenti->SetItem(0, 4, "", unCheck);
    lstUtenti->SetItem(0, 5, "", check);
```

Comment: I don't think it is supported. You can try wxDVC (wxDataViewControll) with the custom renderer. But on MSW the native wxListCtrl does not support this. And so there is no such support in the generic version.

Comment: I understand...I think I'll make an image whith the same width of the column and I use this workaround. In any case thanks a lot for the reply.